# How to get pid from Processed spawned by TS Exec Function?

Tags: typescript, windows, pid

On Windows and using TypeScript

I have a function which executes another application by command line, I then capture the Pid spawned by this Exec Function, only problem is, it's the Pid of the CMD used to spawn the application, and not the application itself.

```
pid = exec('cd location && python appName.py', (err, data, getter) =>{
   if (err){
      console.log(err)
   }
}).pid;
```

This will return the pid of the CMD used to execute the command.

I want to capture and save the pid so I can later use it to kill the process again by using ps.kill.

```
ps.kill(pid, (err) =>{});
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a few things, a Method I got to work was by using the spawn function to directly execute the function, instead of going through CMD , so the pid returned in that case will be for the correction process.

```
const spawnProcess = spawn(pythonExecutable,[appPath]);
const processID = spawnProcess.pid;
```